# How do I reset method variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

I've included relevant pieces of code that work okay when first launched. When I reset the game I get problem with the variable currentScore. It doesn't reset within the method CalcScore. I can't properly reset it or can't figure out why method CalcScore uses variable currentScore as if it's local variable.

CalcScore is being called often. It's bind to buttons in a test game. I haven't declared variable currentScore within the method so it should be using class variable. When I read currentScore with debug.log after resetting the game it says "currentScore=0". But when I call the method CalcScore (at //#####) it returns old value left before resetting. Help me understand What I did wrong and Why am I stupid.

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour

public int currentScore = 0;
int reward = 100;
int timePassedOrLeft;
double correctAnswer;
float currentTime;

void Start()
{
    levelController = FindObjectOfType<LevelController>();
    score = FindObjectsOfType<Score>();
    ShowDisplayScore();
    timeCount = FindObjectOfType<TimeCount>();
    currentScore = 0;
}

public void CalcScore(string answeredText)
{
    Debug.Log(currentScore); // #####

    bool isTimeLimitActive = levelController.GetTimeLimit();
    timePassedOrLeft = Convert.ToInt32(timeCount.GetLeftTime());
    int answer = int.Parse(answeredText);
    correctAnswer = levelController.GetAnswer();

    if (isTimeLimitActive == false)
    {
        if (answer == correctAnswer)
        {
            currentScore += reward;
             ShowDisplayScore();
        }
        else
        {
            currentScore -= reward;
            ShowDisplayScore();
        }
    }
    else if (isTimeLimitActive)
    {
        if (answer == correctAnswer)
        {
            currentScore += reward;
            ShowDisplayScore();
        }
        else
        {
            currentScore -= reward;
            ShowDisplayScore();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the part that calls method CalcScore

```
public void ReadFromButton(int i)
{
    answeredText = buttontexts[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
    //Debug.Log(answeredText);

    Score score;
    score = FindObjectOfType<Score>();
    score.CalcScore(answeredText);
    score = null;
}
```

And here is part that should reset currentScore. I have 2 instances of Score, so I use Array.

```
    public void RestartGame()
{
    Score[] scores;
    scores = FindObjectsOfType<Score>();

    foreach (var score in scores)
    {
        score.currentScore = 0;
        score.DebugScore();
    }
```

Comment: You actually haven't given us enough code for us to guess what is going on. You should probably provide the Score code as well, but it's hard to know what you should include exactly. Some comments: the `if (isTimeLimitActive)` is superfluous, since both the main and else clause do the same thing. Don't assign null to score in `ReadFrom Button`. That has no purpose since you're exiting the block in which the variable has scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between your description of the issue and the code I have to assume that this is a game made of a single scene, so when you reset the game you stay in the same scene.

So, to solve this, given that we don't have knowledge of all the code you are running that can cause this (your code as it is should work), I suppose the simplest way is to replace the content of Restart Game with the following:

```
public void RestartGame()
{
    Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); 
    SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name);
}
```

~Pino

Comment: Indeed I use single scene and different canvases. Didn't think it was relevant to the issue. Your solution works and I'm going to use it. Though I feel that I'm going to regret not sorting out the issue.

Comment: Well, to sort this out you need to change the code a lot. I can see your coding style is not following any of Unity best practices, so you are still learning. I'm sure that in time you will find out where else in the code you overlooked something. If you want, PM me on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/in/gdefrancesco/) and we can arrange a free revision of your code. I love to give back to the community as I can, so do that ;)